# Rails: how to communicate view controller in AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The case is when user click an add link, if the url already added, there will be a alert otherwise will display a form to add new bookmark. The code below works quite well for checking the duplicated url, but if the url is not duplicated I just don't know how to render a add bookmark (in this case the page will be loaded like a normal non ajax request)

This is the link in view

```
 <%= link_to "add", user_bookmark_add_path(current_user, bookmark), remote: true %>
```

The link will invoke the controller action add

```
# controllers/bookmarks_controller.rb
def add 
  @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end
```

The javascript file

```
# views/bookmarks/add.js.erb
<% if duplicated_url? @bookmark.url %>
   alert("Duplicated")
<% else %>
   # how to render the new bookmark form here
<% end %>
```

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial for new bookmark form.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(bookmark) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>

<% end %>
```

Add id to your link

**.html.erb**

```
 <%= link_to "add", user_bookmark_add_path(current_user, bookmark), remote: true, id: "bookmark" %>
```

Replace your link with partial.

**.js.erb**

```
<% if duplicated_url? @bookmark.url %>
   alert("Duplicated")
<% else %>
   $("#bookmark").replaceWith("<%= j render "form", bookmark: Bookmark.new %>");
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `add.js.erb` file, in the `else` part of the code you can `append` a `partial` to your list like this:

```
$('#your_list').append(
  "<%= escape_javascript(render('your_item_of_the_table_partial')) %>"
);
```

This `partial` can be a list item, a table row, a div with your content, anything. The thing is, you will need a chunk of html to be re-rendered on your screen with the new content.

Example of a list item partial:

```
# _bookmark_item.html.erb
<li><%= @bookmark.url %> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#your_div_id').append('<%= escape_javascript(raw render :partial => 'your_form_partial') %>')
```

This will add the contents of your ruby partial to the DOM.